# Get Contact SMS count and contact call time

Tags: android

is there any way to get contact sms counts and contact call time , does android store them anyway ?

I think there are some content that stores sms information , but I do not want to read  all of the table to know how much sms send for specific user , do you know other way?

Answer (score 0):

may be helpful for you.

```
void ReadContacts(String sort) {
        String[] fields;
        final Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI
        };
        //boolean mShowInvisible = false;
        String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        final String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        m_curContacts = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
        String image = ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI;
       if(image!=null){
           fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI};
       }else{
           fields = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, user_photo};
       }



        myadapter= new MySimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_search, m_curContacts, fields, new int []{R.id.textView1,R.id.imageView1});
        myadapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {            
        public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
            String selection;
            Log.d("hii", "runQuery constraint:"+constraint);
            if(constraint.equals("")){
                selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'" +
                        " AND "+ ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"+"&%#"+"%'";
            }else{
                selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '1'" +
                        " AND "+ ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE '%"+constraint+"%'";
            }

            String[] selectionArgs = null;//new String[]{"'1'"};//, };
            Cursor filter = cr.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
            return filter;
        }

    });
        /*if you want to see all contact and then search*/
       // listview.setAdapter(myadapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long arg3) {
                long _id=0;

                Cursor c = (Cursor) listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String DisplayName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow( ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                c.close();
                 // get the phone number
                 Cursor pCur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                 while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                     number = pCur.getString(pCur .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                 }
                 pCur.close();


                  // get email and type
                 Cursor emailCur = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query( ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
                 while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {
                    email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                     String emailType = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));
                 }
                 emailCur.close();

                 //getting image from contact 
                 _id = Long.parseLong(id);
                 String _image=retrieveContactPhoto(_id);               
                 retriveCallLog(number);                    
                 number= number.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "");  

                int _call=in_call+out_call;
                int _sms=in_sms+out_sms;
                System.out.println(DisplayName+number+_call+_sms+email);

                Intent search = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Search_Add.class);
                search.putExtra("_id", id);
                search.putExtra("name", DisplayName);
                search.putExtra("number", number.toString());
                search.putExtra("image", _image);
                search.putExtra("call", Integer.toString(_call));
                search.putExtra("sms", Integer.toString(_sms));
                search.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(search);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_left_in, R.anim.push_left_out);                   
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected Person:"+DisplayName,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

public String retrieveContactPhoto(long _id) {
        Bitmap photo = null;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Image_user);

                  try {
                      inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(_id)));
                      if (inputStream != null) {                          
                            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);                                                                    
                            ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
                            byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
                            user_photo=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

                            inputStream.close();
                      }else {   

                            System.out.println("input stream is null");
                            BitmapDrawable bmd1 = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user_pic);
                            Bitmap bm1 = bmd1.getBitmap();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                            bm1.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream1);
                            byte[] bitmapdata1 = stream1.toByteArray(); 
                            user_photo = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapdata1, 0);           

                      }           

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  return user_photo;

    }

public void retriveCallLog(String number){          
        Database myDatabase=new Database(CustomGallary.this);
        number= number.replaceAll( "[^\\d]", "");
        Cursor cur=myDatabase.getFirstRecordValue(number);  
        System.out.println("retrive call log()"+cur.getCount());
        if(cur.getCount()>0)
        if(cur!=null)
        {
            cur.moveToFirst();
            in_call=cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Database.RECEIVED_CALL));
            out_call=cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Database.DIALED_CALL));
            in_sms=cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Database.RECEIVED_SMS));
            out_sms=cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Database.SENT_SMS));

            int totalcall=in_call+out_call;
            int totalsms=in_sms+out_sms;
            System.out.println("incomincall:"+in_call+"outgoing:"+out_call);
            cur.close();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO Call and Sms Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        myDatabase.close();

    }

        });
      //  cur.close();

    }
```